# Screen recording for a specific area in Android application

Tags: android, image-processing, ffmpeg, screenshot, video-capture

I need to record a video within a moving rectangular area on the image.

Now I simply create bitmaps for each frame while moving the rectangle. Then I pick a video file from images using ffmpeg.

This requires a lot of time and memory especially for temporary storage of frames (about 100MB for 5s video).

Is there a quick and easy way for this purpose?